# How can I access a form-Element, which has neither a name or an id?

Tags: forms, htmlunit

How can I access a form-element, which has neither a name or an id?
I didn't find any useful methods for the class HtmlForm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getElementsByTagName` but you should know the structure of html.

For example :

```
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.tizag.com/phpT/examples/formex.php");
HtmlElement form = (HtmlElement) page.getElementsByTagName("form").get(0);
System.out.println(form.asText());
```

The code above lets you access the first form element and prints its content as text to console .

Comment: Yeah, but I use HtmlUnit and Java. The method getElementByTag didn,t work for the input- and form-tag. DomNodeList is empty.

Comment: Next time please mention what you are using inside the question not just inside tags. So first check the page content using `getContentAsString()` to see if it actually contains the form. Are you using `page.getWebClient().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)` ? 

If you have checked all of these and still unable to access the element try running javascript codes using `executeJavaScript` and read the API about how to get the results back.

Comment: I edited my answer and added an example which I tested and is successfully working in HtmlUnit.